# Which one is more convenient to create django form, CreateView or forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, create-view

I am very beginner in django. I want to create a post form which be able to have title, content, image/file upload and etc. 
I am very confused with concept of modelforms and createview. I tried this:

blog/view.py:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'imagefile']
    success_url = '/blog/home/'
    # template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostCreateView, self).__init__(**kwargs) # Call to ModelForm constructor

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

blog/templates/blog/post_form.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Post::</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <img src='{{ post.imagefile.url }}'>
                <br><br>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

blog/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostCreateView,
)
urlpatterns = [
        path('blog/post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create')
]
```

blog/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    # image = models.ImageField(default='default_post.jpg', upload_to='postimages')
    imagefile = models.FileField(upload_to='postimages', null=True, verbose_name="")


    # if user is deleted the idea should be deleted as
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    # return self.title
    return self.title + ": " + str(self.imagefile)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**My question:** All I want is make a kind of form to create the new post with **title**, **content**, **upload button** and **submit** button. However I don't know if **CreateView** can be customised even for adding further items or forms.Modelforms should be used?

Answer (score 0):

You would want your **view** to be in `views.py` and your **form** to be in `forms.py`. You will need *both*, not one or the other.

Something like:

```
class CreateXYZView(CreateView):
    template_name = "blog/post_form.html"
     model = Post
     form_class = postform



...do view stuff
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Also have a forms.py file

```
class postform(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Post
       widgets = {}
       exclude = ['fieldname']
```

It looks like you are using a model named Post which is a good idea. By declaring `postform` as a `forms.ModelForm` it will pull your model fields into the form I.E from class Post it pulls *title, content, imagefield, etc..* unless the field is specifically added to the exclude parameter. This is useful for parameters in your model like auto fields `created_by` or `post_date` where the user should not fill these in manually. Add these to exclude so they do not show in the form.

You can also manually add form fields in your template after `{{form|crispy}}` but I would avoid that as it creates more work in processing the data.

If you are filling out a form that is not tied to a model you can also use forms.Form:

```
class SupportTicket(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Titlte", max_length=250, widget=forms.TextInput(...)
    content = forms....
```

E.G. use this where the information was being passed directly to GitLab and not saved locally into a model for use later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am a bit confused as you suggested to create a form as postform and never mentioned where should I use it! In my defining a function in view called post_created() and in that one importing PostCreateView(). An in urls, I am calling post_created. However don't know what should I do with postform!

Comment: Hi, 
you already have the form in your template with ```{{ form|crispy }}```.
That will make your form appear. When you hit submit it will take care of the action which is usually a ```post``` action. 

check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/
under the section The View where it has def get_name specifically request.method == 'POST'.
When you submit your form it should trigger a post action which the view then picks up. Then you do your logic I.e. form.is_valid(). If you need specific validation like post date must be >= today then put is_valid() into your forms.py